# What type of regression, or other analysis can I use?

Tags: regression

I have a data set from a survey with yes/no answers, coded as 1 and 0. Thus, both the dependent and independent variables will be binominal. Can I run a binominal logistic regression when both DV and IV are measures yes/no?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run a binomial logistic regression when both DV and IV are binary (that is yes/no) variables. But this will be very similar to a contingency table analysis! For details see

- [Chi-squared test and logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115835/chi-squared-test-and-logistic-regression/517511#517511)
- [Logistic regression and the 2 by 2, or 3 by 2 contingency table](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/128634/logistic-regression-and-the-2-by-2-or-3-by-2-contingency-table)